# How to prove complement of generalized Cantor set is dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Related to a [question I asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491104/generalized-cantor-set-how-much-being-left-behind-at-each-iteration).:

Let $F$ be the subset of $[0,1]$ constructed in the same manner as the Cantor set except that each of the intervals removed at the $n$th iteration has length $\frac{\alpha}{3^{n}}$ with $0 < \alpha < 1$.

**I need to show that $F$'s complement, $[0,1]\backslash F$ is dense in $[0,1]$.**

I know that a $[0,1]\backslash F$ is dense in $[0,1]$ if any open interval in $[0,1]$ contains a point of $[0,1]\backslash F$.

Obviously, the open intervals in $[0,1]$ comprising $[0,1]\backslash F$ contain points $[0,1]\backslash F$,so, I just need to worry about the open intervals inside $[0,1]$ that are not part of $[0,1]\backslash F$.

However, those would be open intervals inside the Cantor set, and **while I know that the Cantor set does not contain any intervals of positive measure, I don't know how to show this** all epsilon-y (i.e., with neighborhoods, ets). Therefore, I was asking how to formally prove this (either an outline or a full proof is fine; hints are fine, too, if you don't mind follow-up questions.)

Comment: @Arthur, so total length remaining is $1-\alpha$, so a length of $\alpha$ is removed. But, I've got to tell you, I am having a lot of trouble figuring out which points are guaranteed to be removed. I guess it would  be right endpoint of closed interval $+ \epsilon$ and left endpoint of closed interval $-\epsilon$, but because of the $\alpha$'s, as opposed to even $1/3$rds, I am really having trouble visualizing this. Please elaborate more on what you mean. If you turned your comment into an answer with appropriate details, I might be willing to accept your answer and give you points.

Comment: You're right, I was a bit quick making that comment. However, if the complement is _not_ dense in $[0, 1]$, then there must be an open interval somewhere in $F$. That would soon get you into a contradiction.

Comment: @Arthur, again, because of the $\alpha$, it is not $1$ like it is with the usual Cantor set, I'm not sure how to write out that contradiction. I have an idea that suppose $[0,1]\backslash F$ is not dense in $[0,1]$. Then, $F$ must contain some open interval  $(a,b)$ (does it need to be a NONEMPTY open interval? Seems it would defeat the purpose w/o this condition).  Suppose that $(a,b)$ is nonempty (i.e., where $a \neq b$). Then, choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{\alpha}{3^{n}}<b-a$.  Since $F$ is contained in a countable intersection of closed intervals, all of length $< (b-a)$...

Comment: @Arthur (continued from above), and on each iteration, the lengths of the intervals decreases, this intersection cannot contain $(a,b)$.

Is that correct? If not, please let me know specifically what to change about it.

Comment: First of all, the total "length" (the measure) of $F$ isn't necessarily $0$. The total length of all the removed intervals is actually $\alpha$, so $1-\alpha$ is left in $F$. But at each iteration, every component is divided into two equal parts (and then some is removed), so for each iteration, the length of the longest interval contained in the set becomes less than half of what it was. From there it's easy to see that there cannot be any positive-length intervals left in $F$.

Comment: @Arthur, maybe I'm not clear as to the correct definition of a dense subset. I thought it meant if $A \subset B$ is dense in $B$, then, $\exists$ an open interval $(a,b) \in B$ containing $x \in A$. How does that coincide with the idea that if $[0,1]\backslash F$ is not dense in $[0,1]$, then $F$ must contain an open interval? I'm so confused! It's not true that if $A^{c}$ is dense then $A$ cannot be - look at the rationals and irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No, if $A\subset B$ is dense, then that means that _every_ open set $U\subset B$ intersects with $A$. That is the same as saying that no non-empty open set in $B$ is contained in the complement of $A$. In this case, we want to prove that no non-empty open set in $[0,1]$ is contained in $F$.

Comment: @Arthur, rigorously, how would I express that there are no positive length intervals left in $F$? in a way compatible with my assumption to the contrary that $(a,b)$ is contained in $F$? Please be specific.

Comment: @Arthur, eventually, for large enough $n$, we want the total length removed on that $n$th iteration, $\frac{\alpha 2^{n-1}}{3^{n}}$, to be less than $b-a$ for any $(a,b)$, but you can't just say that it's going to be, or that it's obvious/easy to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30589/discussion-between-jessy-cat-and-arthur).

Comment: Please join me in chat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $F_i$ be the result of the $i$-th iteration of removing all the $\alpha/3^i$ wide open intervals. That means $F_0 = [0,1]$, $F_1 = [0,\frac12-\frac\alpha6]\cup [\frac12 + \frac\alpha6, 1]$ and so on. We then have $F = \bigcap_i F_i$.

Now, every $F_i$ consists of $2^i$ disjoint, closed intervals of equal length. That means that each such closed interval is less than $1/2^i$ wide.

Assume $(a, b) \subseteq F$ with $a < b$. That means that $(a, b) \subseteq F_i$ for all $i$, by definition of $\bigcap$. But that can't be true, since $b-a > 1/2^k$ for some $k$, and in the corresponding $F_k$ there is no room for an interval of that width.

Therefore there can be no non-empty open interval in $F$, which makes the complement of $F$ dense.

Comment: Why not just assuming F is dense, then it must intersect every open interval inside [0,1], then use the interval $(5\alpha/12,6\alpha/12)$ as an open interval which does not intersect $F_1$ and consequently does not intersect F? That is, an open interval which is inside the middle removed set at the first step. That will show that F is not dense, Hence [0,1]\F is dense.

Comment: @RichardClare A set can be dense and have a dense complement (the rationals in the reals, for instance). A set can be nondense and have nondense complement (the positive reals in the reals, for instance). So it doesn't help to show that $F$ isn't dense. Showing that $F$ is _nowhere dense_, on the other hand, that would help. But that takes a bit more work.

Comment: Arthur, but [0,1] is dense, and is the union of F and F complement is [0,1] so if F isn’t dense, F complement must be ?!?

Comment: @RichardClare The exact same can be said about $F_1$ instead of $F$, but the complement of $F_1$ isn't dense in $[0,1]$. Just because a set isn't dense, doesn't mean its complement must be.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So what you have proved is that F is nowhere dense?

Comment: @RichardClare No. I've proven that the complement of $F$ is dense, which is a weaker statement than $F$ being nowhere dense. I did this by showing that every non-empty interval contains points from said complement, which is the definition of "dense".

Comment: It would be very useful for me to have a general expression for the $F_i$’s and the $O_i$’s which are the sets removed. Did you know such formula? I know it can be written recursively and I have been trying to find it with no luck

Comment: No, I do not. You could try to ask a new question to address this.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The length of any of the closed intervals not removed by step $n$ have length at most $2^{-n}$.

Comment: Any of the individual closed intervals? Or the complete amount removed??? I'm still so confused...And how would doing that show me that no open interval is in there???

Comment: anyway, are you sure you don't mean $3^{-n}$

Comment: What you are trying to show is that the union of all the open intervals removed is dense. What does it say if the maximum distance between any two open intervals is at most $2^{-n}$?

Comment: I don't know. I seriously don't.

Comment: Remember that you are dividing each closed interval into two closed interval by adding an open interval in the middle..

Comment: that the maximum distance between any two open intervals is the length of one of the closed ones? But again, please answer me: why at most $2^{-n}$ and not $3^{-n}$

Comment: How far can *any* point be from an open interval at step $n$?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe $1-\frac{\alpha}{3^{n}}$, but I really don't know.

Comment: Please explain to me why the maximum distance between any two open intervals is $2^{-n}$.

Comment: Where did epsilon come from? If the length of any of the closed intervals not removed at step $n$ is at most $2^{-n}$, the distance between one open interval and the next is at most $2^{-n}$. Now answer my last question.

Comment: Is it $2^{-n}$? Or $2^{-n}$ multiplied by however many intervals there are?

Comment: my professor says Use that to show that every open interval contains an interval of complement of the set left at the nth step (and that interval is also in the complement of F).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30593/discussion-between-jessy-cat-and-robjohn).

Comment: But I don't understand what he means.

Comment: The distance between two adjacent open intervals is the length of the closed interval in between. At step $n$, we have divided the unit interval in two $n$ times, so the length of any of the closed intervals is less than $2^{-n}$. Thus, the distance between any open interval and the next open interval is less than $2^{-n}$. What is the greatest distance *any* point can be from the union of the open intervals if the distance between any two adjacent open intervals is less than $2^{-n}$?

Comment: is it 1-2^{n}? If not, please tell me.

Comment: Please read my last comment and draw a picture if necessary.

Comment: (------)[------](------) If the closed interval between the two open intervals has length $2^{-n}$, then how far can a point inside the closed interval be from the union of the open intervals?

Comment: you didn't say a point inside the closed interval

Comment: I have to go now... please read and try to understand what I have written above.

Comment: @JessyCat: a point inside an open interval is a distance of $0$ from the union of the open intervals; the only other points are those inside the closed intervals.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?  What is wrong with my hint? It shows that the greatest distance from a point not in the union of the open intervals to any point in $[0,1]$ is less than $2^{-n}$ after step $n$.

Comment: @JessyCat: I thought the hint was enough. Sorry you didn't think so. I asked questions since that is usually a better way for people to understand rather than giving them a complete answer to copy.  If you had said that you were only interested in a complete answer rather than understanding what is going on, it would have saved us both a lot of time.